# How to close the connection if the host does not respond within 5 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write program, that will check which proxies are active.
When my script tries to connect to inactive proxies, it takes up to even about 30 seconds. When I check list of thousands proxies it increases the working time of the script by a few hours.

Is it possible to break this function if it takes more than 5 seconds to respond?

```
def get(url, proxy):
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://'+proxy,
    'https': 'https://'+proxy
}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
s.proxies = proxies
r = s.get(url)
return [r.status_code, r.reason, r.text]

with open('proxy.txt') as ips:
for ip in ips:
    ip = ip.split('\n', 1)[0]
    try:
        get(url, ip)
        with open('working.txt', 'a') as the_file:
            the_file.write(ip+'\n')
    except:
        print("error")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `timeout` kwarg with `s.get`. `s.get(url, timeout=5)`